# Help Creating a bookmarklet out of this code

Tags: javascript, string, bookmarklet

I'm really stuck here and I've tried a bunch of different solutions to try to fix the problem, but I can't seem to find a solution. The problem is that I'm trying to create a bookmarklet (a button that you press on a website that activates JavaScript code ie: http://erkie.github.com/) out of this code:

```
(div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 100; ")  (embed src="http://www.netdisaster.com/fla/ufo.swf?mode=ufo&movie=ufo&destruction=massive&control=on&son=&linkTarget=_self&acces=http://www.netdisaster.com/fla/" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="100%" height="100%") (/div)
```

I've tried variations such as:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+="  (divstyle='position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:20;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:420;')  (embedsrc='http://www.netdisaster.com/fla/ufo.swf?mode=ufo&destruction=massive&control=on&son='quality='High'wmode='transparent')  (/embed)  (/div")
```

and other ways such as replacing the spaces with `%20`, but I still can't seem to get it to work.

I found [this site](http://cardfire.net/videos.htm): when you click on the word "we" it produces something similar. I had to get rid of the carrot signs since it won't show up on this website if I have them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jQuery Bookmarklet Generator](http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your div bookmarklet:

```
javascript:
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += '<div id="working" style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; right:20; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:420;><embed src="http://www.netdisaster.com/fla/ufo.swf?mode=ufo&destruction=massive&control=on&son=" quality="High" wmode="transparent"></embed></div>';
void(0);
```

Check for '/" problems! Also, you don't want to get rid of spaces, they help you understand the code. And, I've put the div into "head" instead of "html" as it is simpler.

1. Make the code in normal javascript.
2. Go to http://dean.edwards.name/packer/
3. Obfuscate the code so it is shorter.